# how to get users from firestore database with Like query

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

this function work fine with equal string but i need to search a substring: if i write "h" and the string is "hello" i need to return that

```
async getUsers(searchUser) {
            
            return firestore().collection('Users').where(searchUser).where('firstName', '==', searchUser)
            .limit(20).get().then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
                    const usersData = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
                    return usersData
                });
            })
        }
```

Comment: Are they small in number? If so, another alternative is to get all of them and search on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you answer!
In that case, you must use a dedicated third-party search service. These services provide advanced indexing and search capabilities far beyond what any simple database query can offer.
Please use "Algolia" and at that time your code according to your expectations  must be like this.

```
const client = algoliasearch('YourApplicationID', 'YourSearchOnlyAPIKey');
const index = client.initIndex('firstName');
index.search(searchUser, {
  attributesToRetrieve: ['firstname', 'lastname'/*, .. etc the fields you need*/],
  hitsPerPage: 20 /* the page Size */,
}).then(({ hits }) => {
  console.log(hits); // the results you want
});
```

Just try it.
Helpful for you? If it's successful, I would be happy.
If you have a question please contact "Nykolai.B0411@outlook.com". I will help you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you register a new user to your app you can store their username/firstname in firestore as an array that includes the possible ways you would search for a user (look at the attached image). You can do that by splitting the name string.

[image: search options array in user doc in firestore]

then you can query the users collection by searching in that array using `arrayContains` like this:

```
await usersCollection
        .where('searchOptions', arrayContains: searchText)
        .get()
        .then((value) =>
            value.docs.map((doc) => User.fromSnapShot(doc)).toList());
```

If you need more capabilities than that you might need to use a 3rd party service. but this solution should be sufficient for your case.